# What is the underlying mechanism that Terraform’s AWS Provider uses to provision resources in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

Does it use AWS CloudFormation, the AWS CLI, or does it do something else like directly make AWS API calls without going through the CLI?

Answer (score 4):

No, it not using the AWS CLI or cloud formation.

AWS terraform use the AWS SDK and here you can see the complete list of dependency for the [AWS Terraform provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/go.mod).

It also uses aws-sdk-go  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws